# Why do I need $rootScope.$apply when inside $rootScope.$on?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Why is `$rootScope.$apply()` needed in this example to update elements using `ng-hide` on the page?

In my experience whenever I put `$scope.$apply()` inside a `$scope.$watch` I get the "digest already in progress" error. Is this different?

```
app.component('myComponent', {
    controller: function(){
        $scope.visible = false;

        $rootScope.$on('someEvent', function(){
            $scope.visible = true;
            $rootScope.$apply(); // why?
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: Nothing shown suggests it is needed. Provide a [mcve] We can't guess at your situation

Comment: $rootScope.$apply() is needed when you want to manually run the digest cycle so if anything happens out of the context of angular which modify the angular variables you have to manuallly fire the digest cycle.once the digest cycle is running and u try apply it will give u that error

Comment: I don't think it is needed in this case. `$scope.$on` is already calling digest cycle so every changes inside the function will be updated already.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Callback registered with `$rootScope.$on` is triggered by either [$rootScope.$broadcast](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/f5f802c6e68a3d4e22f5e7725057652519d15e60/src/ng/rootScope.js#L1266) or [$rootScope.$emit](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/f5f802c6e68a3d4e22f5e7725057652519d15e60/src/ng/rootScope.js#L1194). If you explore these methods source code you will see that these methods by itself do not trigger `$digest` cycle (dirty-checking). That means, that `$digest` should be triggered either by the code that calls `$broadcast` or `$emit`, or inside a callback registered with `$rootScope.$on`.

Usually, it's better to assume that callback is triggered inside `$digest` loop and it means that callback call should be wrapped with `$apply`, as in:

```
$rootScope.$apply($rootScope.$broadcast('event', data));
```

This is consistent with what angular best practices [suggest](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/wiki/When-to-use-$scope.$apply()):

> $scope.$apply() should occur as close to the async event binding as
>   possible.

Answer (score 0):

I can imagine that `$scope.$apply` is necessary if you want to support events from outside AngularJS world. Take a look and consider differences how to support events from AngularJS (ng-click) and jQuery (onClick).

```js
angular.module('app', [])
  .controller('ctrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.click = function() {
      $scope.$emit('inside', {
        message: 'from AngularJS world'
      })
    }
  })
  .directive('eventListener', function() {
    return {
      restrict: 'E',
      controller: function($scope) {
        $scope.message = 'listening'

        // in AngularJS context - $apply will throw error that $digest is already running!
        $scope.$on('inside', function(event, args) {
          $scope.message = args.message
        })

        // let to know AngularJS that something changes
        $scope.$on('outside', function(event, args) {
          $scope.$apply(function() {
              $scope.message = args.message
            }) // this is eqvivalent to:
            /*
            $scope.message = args.message
            $scope.$apply()
            */
        })
      },
      template: '<div>message: {{ message }}</div>'
    }
  })
  .directive('jQueryClick', function() {
    return {
      restrict: 'E',
      link: function(scope, element) {
        $(element).on('click', function() {
          scope.$emit('outside', {
            message: 'outside AngularJS'
          })
        })
      },
      template: '<div><button click="click()">jQuery - onClick()!</button></div>',
    }
  })
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app="app">
  <div ng-controller="ctrl">
    <button ng-click="click()">AngularJS ng-click!</button>
  </div>
  <div>
    <j-query-click></j-query-click>
  </div>
  <div>
    <event-listener></event-listener>
  </div>
</div>
```

As this will be hard to decide what is the source of change and how it should be applied to the **$scope** we can move **$apply** from **$on** to **$emit** part.

```js
angular.module('app', [])
  .controller('ctrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.click = function() {
      $scope.$emit('message', {
        message: 'from AngularJS world'
      })
    }
  })
  .directive('eventListener', function() {
    return {
      restrict: 'E',
      controller: function($scope) {
        $scope.message = 'listening'

        /*
         * We are goint to support internal and external message in the same way,
         * we can simplify support for it
         *
        $scope.$on('inside', function(event, args) {
          $scope.message = args.message
        })

        $scope.$on('outside', function(event, args) {
          $scope.message = args.message
        })
        */

        $scope.$on('message', function(event, args) {
          $scope.message = args.message
        })
      },
      template: '<div>message: {{ message }}</div>'
    }
  })
  .directive('jQueryClick', function() {
    return {
      restrict: 'E',
      link: function(scope, element) {
        $(element).on('click', function() {
          scope.$apply(scope.$emit('message', {
            message: 'outside AngularJS'
          }))
        })
      },
      template: '<div><button click="click()">jQuery - onClick()!</button></div>',
    }
  })
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app="app">
  <div ng-controller="ctrl">
    <button ng-click="click()">AngularJS ng-click!</button>
  </div>
  <div>
    <j-query-click></j-query-click>
  </div>
  <div>
    <event-listener></event-listener>
  </div>
</div>
```